# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement discord-componentsERROR: No matching distribution found for discord-components

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, components, discord-buttons

[I got this error while Developing a Ticket Tool discord Bot Plz help me to solve this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMMjG.jpg)

`

```
import discord
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import Button, Select, SelectOption, ComponentsBot, interaction
from discord_components.component import ButtonStyle
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py 2.0 has built in buttons with `discord.ui.buttons` use it instead.
[Read the documentation here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#discord.ui.button). There are also plenty of tutorials on it.

Comment: what can i do to remove this error?

Comment: discord-components package is no longer developed since 2021 (archived), and thus has no Python 3.10 support. Try downgrading to Python 3.9. But really, use the discord.py library instead, it is back in development so it will be more beneficial to use it in the long run.

Comment: I am using discord.py Library